# Are there any tools to convert c/c++ source code to html?

Tags: c++, navigation, kindle

I want to a tool which can convert c/c++ source code files to HTML files. So far all tools I have found, like [src-highlite](http://www.gnu.org/software/src-highlite/), [highlight](http://www.andre-simon.de/), can only do syntax highlighting. The critical feature I want is to navigate over code and when my mouse moves over a classname, I can click the hyperlink and it takes me to the definition file of the class.

Then I can package these HTML files into a .mobi file, so I can read source code on my kindle.

Does anybody know?

Comment: c/c++ -> html. Sounds like an oxymoron.

Comment: To generate something like [Linux Cross Reference](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/) with syntax highlight?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Have you checked out [Doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/)?

It will generate documentation from your comments too. There's lot of other cool features like a class graph, file dependencies graph, and of course just HTML files of the source.

For an example of the output, check out the [KDE library API reference](http://api.kde.org/4.7-api/kdelibs-apidocs/).

Comment: yes! this is exactly what I want, Thank you:) In fact I ever used Doxyen about a year ago, I remind that it could embeds the whole source code along with comments into HTML.

Comment: KDE API reference moved to: https://api.kde.org/ but it uses a layer on top that makes it hard to see where the Doxygen starts. https://www.doxygen.nl/results.html has a list of sample projects of which Eigen for example is more raw: https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/ Here's a sample indexed file: https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/ArithmeticSequence_8h_source.html Every cross-link links back to the doc page rather than more source however, which makes the use case of browsing source a bit annoying. Maybe  there's a setting for that.

Answer (score 1):

check enscript: http://linux.die.net/man/1/enscript

```
nscript --color -Ecpp -fCourier8 *.cpp -o - |ps2pdf - output.pdf
```

Answer (score 1):

Or use `vim`, open the file, and issue `:TOhtml`.

Answer (score 0):

Exilir https://github.com/bootlin/elixir is another option.

It is used e.g. at https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source which indexes the Linux kernel.

Here's a sample source file: https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v6.7.9/source/init/main.c#L230 If you try clicking some definitions you can quickly jump to possible definitions and reference lists.

From the project README:

> Elixir is a source code cross-referencer inspired by LXR. It’s written in Python and its main purpose is to index every release of a C or C++ project (like the Linux kernel) while keeping a minimal footprint.
>
> It uses Git as a source-code file store and Berkeley DB for cross-reference data. Internally, it indexes Git blobs rather than trees of files to avoid duplicating work and data. It has a straightforward data structure (reminiscent of older LXR releases) to keep queries simple and fast.

https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source was previously [mentioned by Franklin Yu on a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8257190/are-there-any-tools-to-convert-c-c-source-code-to-html/78123140#comment71336482_8257190).